# how do I Return a String that is { "a", "b", "c"......} in a type String[]

Tags: java

I have a method (below).  I want to it to return what 'str.trim()' produces.
'str.trim()' produces below `JSON`.  Question is how do I return this?  Currently, I'm returning the method itself, `getData()` which is not good.  Also, the return type needs to be `String[]` because I need to pass this return into an Object.

**`str.trim()` produces this:  `{ "a",  "b",  "c" }`**

----------------------method------------------------

```
      private String[] getData() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(output);
            sb.append(output + "");


        }
        String content = sb.toString();
        String str = content.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}");
        //System.out.println(content.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}"));
        System.out.println(str.trim());



        conn.disconnect();


      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    return getData();
```

Comment: cant you just `return str.trim();` ?

Comment: Uhm: `str.trim() produces this:  { "a",  "b",  "c" }`...no it doesn't....

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!  resolved.

I needed to assign a new variable on the top.
assign it to the str.split();

It works now!!